# Ruby -how can I gets the keys in a hash that have multiple values?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have this hash:

```
@@MAPPINGS= {A: 2, B: 2, C: 2, D: 3, E: 3, F: 3, G: 4, H: 4, I: 4, J: 5, K: 5, L: 5, M: 6, N: 6, O: 6, P: 7, Q: 7, R: 7, S: 7, T: 8, U: 8, V: 8, W: 9, X: 9, Y: 9, Z: 9}
```

I want the key-value pairs that match a given value, e.g. for a value of 3 I want

```
{D: 3, E: 3, F: 3)
```

I tried:

```
@@MAPPINGS.keys[3]
```

and got

```
=> :D
```

and

```
@@MAPPINGS[3].keys
```

but got

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: you want key/value or only keys ?

Comment: Michael, recall that the Ruby convention is to use snake-case when naming variables (and methods): `@@mappings` or `@@my_mappings`.

Comment: Would you like `@@MAPPINGS.reject { |_,val| val != 3 }` ? :-) Other option.

Answer (score 4):

Doing

```
@@MAPPINGS.select { |key,val| val == 3 }
```

was one option

Comment: Since you are not using key value, just do `|_, val|`